# Highchart spline Chart with no markers and legends markers as circle's

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can anyone help me with this, I need the following legend marker symbol marked in the image as a circle?

I have tried adding **marker: circle** inside series but it is not working.

I am new to Highcharts. Is there any possible way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: here is the image]

**NOTE: My chart has multiple series.**

```
{
  "series": [{
    "name": "Test series",
    "data": [{

      "y": 8,

    }, {

      "y": 10,

    }, {

      "y": 15,

    }, {

      "y": 8,

    }],
    "type": "spline",
    "color": "#dd0014",
    marker: {
      symbol: 'circle'
    }
  }],
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["cat-1", "cat-2", "cat-3"],
  },

  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle",
        "enabled": false
      },

    },


  },
  "legend": {
    "align": "right",
    "enabled": true,
    "y": 35,
    "x": 0,
    "verticalAlign": "top",
    "layout": "vertical",
    "itemStyle": {
      "fontSize": "12px",
      "fontWeight": "light"
    },
    "reversed": true,
    "symbolRadius": 9,
    "itemMarginTop": 3,
    "itemMarginBottom": 3,
    "marker": "circle"
  },
  "colors": ["#00B19D", "#4E3363", "#3A99D5", "#00AE84", "#49494A", "#318ACA"],
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },



}
```

[JsFiddle Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/krishna_kanth/s6me2570/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround solution after going through the Highcharts documentation.

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('d', "M 8 14.75 Z 61.25 61.25 99 1 1 33.45 44.00");
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr("stroke-linecap", "round");
      },
      redraw: function() {
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('d', "M 8 14.75 Z 61.25 61.25 99 1 1 33.45 44.00");
        $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr("stroke-linecap", "round");
      }
    }
  },
```

added this to update legend symbols using JQUERY

[DEMO LINK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/krishna_kanth/bmhvgfp9/1/)